# Corda 4- Due Diligence App issue while sharing auditing result

Tags: corda, corda-flow

I am running duediligence-cordapp from corda Github repository, there are certain steps given in README file which I am following however when I reach to second half of Step 3 where I need to run flow start ShareAuditingResultInitiator AuditingResultID: , sendTo: BankB, trustedAuditorAttachment: "8DF3275D80B26B9A45AB022F2FDA4A2ED996449B425F8F2245FA5BCF7D1AC587" the only output that I get at console is Starting and looking at the log of NodeA I get

[INFO ] 2022-12-19T10:06:45,659Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Error 1 of 1: {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=BankA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000003, flow-id=12a99e9f-b6ef-4760-beff-6012fa3c1e71, invocation_id=40e9a1e6-8368-40c6-8431-1647e831613c, invocation_timestamp=2022-12-19T10:06:45.610Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=5b95a19b-922a-4bb2-8b2e-2ca47ba07c8d, session_timestamp=2022-12-19T10:03:29.151Z, thread-id=208}
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$OverlappingAttachmentsException: Multiple attachments define a file at whitelistedcorporateauditors.txt., transaction: 39A5A6E51772394DF7AB935E60DA9F36F639131F18CC6BEA63520411FD22943B
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoader.checkAttachments(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:307) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoader.(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:152) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:356) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:333) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2337) ~[caffeine-2.7.0.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2335) ~[caffeine-2.7.0.jar:?]
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2318) ~[caffeine-2.7.0.jar:?]
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:111) ~[caffeine-2.7.0.jar:?]
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:54) ~[caffeine-2.7.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderCacheImpl.computeIfAbsent(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:476) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:354) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$default(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:348) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.internalPrepareVerify$core(LedgerTransaction.kt:260) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:250) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:675) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.samples.duediligence.flows.ShareAuditingResult$ShareAuditingResultInitiator.call(ShareAuditingResult.java:70) ~[?:?]
at net.corda.samples.duediligence.flows.ShareAuditingResult$ShareAuditingResultInitiator.call(ShareAuditingResult.java:23) ~[?:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:349) ~[corda-node-4.9.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:71) ~[corda-node-4.9.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1108) ~[quasar-core-0.7.14_r3.jar:0.7.14_r3]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:804) ~[quasar-core-0.7.14_r3.jar:0.7.14_r3]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:103) ~[quasar-core-0.7.14_r3.jar:0.7.14_r3]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:94) ~[quasar-core-0.7.14_r3.jar:0.7.14_r3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.9.jar:?]

I cleared all my temp files, did a clean build so that all Nodes get created again as it looks like I may have multiple files of same name, but though am not able to figure out why I am not able to share auditing result from Node A to Node B.

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, it looks like there is something wrong with uploading the attachment to the node. Can you verify that that step is properly done?

```
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$OverlappingAttachmentsException: Multiple attachments define a file at
whitelistedcorporateauditors.txt., transaction: 39A5A6E51772394DF7AB935E60DA9F36F639131F18CC6BEA63520411FD22943B at 
net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoader.checkAttachments(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:307) ~[corda-core-4.9.jar:?] at
```